# Why does GCC (MinGW-w64) return a 'fatal error: no input files' when building MPFR?

Tags: c, mingw, mingw-w64, gmp, mpfr

I'm unable to diagnose the cause of an error when attempting to build MPFR 4.0.1 with MinGW-w64 8.1.0. I'm using msys2 and Windows 10. The result of running mingw32-make is:

```
$ make
Making all in doc
make[1]: Entering directory 'C:/development-personal-builds/mpfr-4.0.1/build-1/doc'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make[1]: Leaving directory 'C:/development-personal-builds/mpfr-4.0.1/build-1/doc'
Making all in src
make[1]: Entering directory 'C:/development-personal-builds/mpfr-4.0.1/build-1/src'
C:/development-tools/mingw-w64-8.1.0/mingw64/bin/make  all-am
make[2]: Entering directory 'C:/development-personal-builds/mpfr-4.0.1/build-1/src'
C:/development-tools/msys2/usr/bin/sh.exe ../libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DMPFR_WANT_ASSERT=1 -DHAVE_INTTYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_STDINT_H=1 -DLT_OBJDIR=\".libs/\" -DHAVE_DOUBLE_IEEE_LITTLE_ENDIAN=1 -DHAVE_LITTLE_ENDIAN=1 -DTIME_WITH_SYS_TIME=1 -DHAVE_LOCALE_H=1 -DHAVE_WCHAR_H=1 -DHAVE_STDARG=1 -DHAVE_SYS_TIME_H=1 -DHAVE_STRUCT_LCONV_DECIMAL_POINT=1 -DHAVE_STRUCT_LCONV_THOUSANDS_SEP=1 -DHAVE_VA_COPY=1 -DHAVE_SETLOCALE=1 -DHAVE_GETTIMEOFDAY=1 -DHAVE_SIGNAL=1 -DHAVE_LONG_LONG=1 -DHAVE_INTMAX_T=1 -DMPFR_HAVE_INTMAX_MAX=1 -DMPFR_PRINTF_MAXLM=\"ll\" -DMPFR_HAVE_NORETURN=1 -DMPFR_HAVE_BUILTIN_UNREACHABLE=1 -DMPFR_HAVE_CONSTRUCTOR_ATTR=1 -DHAVE_PTHREAD_PRIO_INHERIT=1 -DHAVE_PTHREAD=1 -DMPFR_HAVE_FESETROUND=1 -DHAVE_DENORMS=1 -DHAVE_DENORMS_FLT=1 -DHAVE_SIGNEDZ=1 -DHAVE_ROUND=1 -DHAVE_TRUNC=1 -DHAVE_FLOOR=1 -DHAVE_CEIL=1 -DHAVE_NEARBYINT=1 -DHAVE_LDOUBLE_IEEE_EXT_LITTLE=1 -DMPFR_USE_THREAD_SAFE=1 -DMPFR_USE_C11_THREAD_SAFE=1 -DMPFR_WANT_DECIMAL_FLOATS=1 -DMPFR_WANT_FLOAT128=1 -DMPFR_USE_STATIC_ASSERT=1 -DHAVE_CLOCK_GETTIME=1 -DHAVE_ATTRIBUTE_MODE=1 -DNPRINTF_J=1 -DNPRINTF_L=1 -DNPRINTF_T=1 -DHAVE___GMPN_SBPI1_DIVAPPR_Q=1 -DHAVE___GMPN_INVERT_LIMB=1 -DHAVE___GMPN_RSBLSH_N=1 -DMPFR_LONG_WITHIN_LIMB=1 -I. -I../../src/src   -IC:/development-personal-builds/gmp-6.1.2/build-1/include  -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -Wpointer-arith -O2 -pedantic -fomit-frame-pointer -m64 -mtune=k8 -march=k8 -MT exceptions.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/exceptions.Tpo -c -o exceptions.lo ../../src/src/exceptions.c
libtool: compile:  gcc -DMPFR_WANT_ASSERT=1 -DHAVE_INTTYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_STDINT_H=1 "-DLT_OBJDIR=\\.libs/\" -DHAVE_DOUBLE_IEEE_LITTLE_ENDIAN=1 -DHAVE_LITTLE_ENDIAN=1 -DTIME_WITH_SYS_TIME=1 -DHAVE_LOCALE_H=1 -DHAVE_WCHAR_H=1 -DHAVE_STDARG=1 -DHAVE_SYS_TIME_H=1 -DHAVE_STRUCT_LCONV_DECIMAL_POINT=1 -DHAVE_STRUCT_LCONV_THOUSANDS_SEP=1 -DHAVE_VA_COPY=1 -DHAVE_SETLOCALE=1 -DHAVE_GETTIMEOFDAY=1 -DHAVE_SIGNAL=1 -DHAVE_LONG_LONG=1 -DHAVE_INTMAX_T=1 -DMPFR_HAVE_INTMAX_MAX=1 -DMPFR_PRINTF_MAXLM=\"ll\" -DMPFR_HAVE_NORETURN=1 -DMPFR_HAVE_BUILTIN_UNREACHABLE=1 -DMPFR_HAVE_CONSTRUCTOR_ATTR=1 -DHAVE_PTHREAD_PRIO_INHERIT=1 -DHAVE_PTHREAD=1 -DMPFR_HAVE_FESETROUND=1 -DHAVE_DENORMS=1 -DHAVE_DENORMS_FLT=1 -DHAVE_SIGNEDZ=1 -DHAVE_ROUND=1 -DHAVE_TRUNC=1 -DHAVE_FLOOR=1 -DHAVE_CEIL=1 -DHAVE_NEARBYINT=1 -DHAVE_LDOUBLE_IEEE_EXT_LITTLE=1 -DMPFR_USE_THREAD_SAFE=1 -DMPFR_USE_C11_THREAD_SAFE=1 -DMPFR_WANT_DECIMAL_FLOATS=1 -DMPFR_WANT_FLOAT128=1 -DMPFR_USE_STATIC_ASSERT=1 -DHAVE_CLOCK_GETTIME=1 -DHAVE_ATTRIBUTE_MODE=1 -DNPRINTF_J=1 -DNPRINTF_L=1 -DNPRINTF_T=1 -DHAVE___GMPN_SBPI1_DIVAPPR_Q=1 -DHAVE___GMPN_INVERT_LIMB=1 -DHAVE___GMPN_RSBLSH_N=1 -DMPFR_LONG_WITHIN_LIMB=1 -I. -I../../src/src -IC:/development-personal-builds/gmp-6.1.2/build-1/include -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -Wpointer-arith -O2 -pedantic -fomit-frame-pointer -m64 -mtune=k8 -march=k8 -MT exceptions.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/exceptions.Tpo -c -o exceptions.lo ../../src/src/exceptions.c"  -DDLL_EXPORT -DPIC -o .libs/exceptions.o
gcc.exe: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [Makefile:807: exceptions.lo] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory 'C:/development-personal-builds/mpfr-4.0.1/build-1/src'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:476: all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory 'C:/development-personal-builds/mpfr-4.0.1/build-1/src'
make: *** [Makefile:498: all-recursive] Error 1
```

The command used to execute configure was:

```
cd build-1
../src/configure \
--prefix=C:/development-personal-builds/mpfr-4.0.1/build-1 \
--build=x86_64-w64-mingw32 \
--enable-assert \
--enable-shared=yes \
--enable-static=no \
--with-gmp=C:/development-personal-builds/gmp-6.1.2/build-1
```

The GMP build I supplied was built by me and it passed all 'make check' tests.

**Attempts to Fix**
Following advice given by Mike, I've fed gcc the corrected string via the CC flag, but get a new error as gcc can only write to one file:

```
CC="--mode=compile gcc -DMPFR_WANT_ASSERT=1 -DHAVE_INTTYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_STDINT_H=1 -DLT_OBJDIR=\".libs/\" -DHAVE_DOUBLE_IEEE_LITTLE_ENDIAN=1 -DHAVE_LITTLE_ENDIAN=1 -DTIME_WITH_SYS_TIME=1 -DHAVE_LOCALE_H=1 -DHAVE_WCHAR_H=1 -DHAVE_STDARG=1 -DHAVE_SYS_TIME_H=1 -DHAVE_STRUCT_LCONV_DECIMAL_POINT=1 -DHAVE_STRUCT_LCONV_THOUSANDS_SEP=1 -DHAVE_VA_COPY=1 -DHAVE_SETLOCALE=1 -DHAVE_GETTIMEOFDAY=1 -DHAVE_SIGNAL=1 -DHAVE_LONG_LONG=1 -DHAVE_INTMAX_T=1 -DMPFR_HAVE_INTMAX_MAX=1 -DMPFR_PRINTF_MAXLM=\"ll\" -DMPFR_HAVE_NORETURN=1 -DMPFR_HAVE_BUILTIN_UNREACHABLE=1 -DMPFR_HAVE_CONSTRUCTOR_ATTR=1 -DHAVE_PTHREAD_PRIO_INHERIT=1 -DHAVE_PTHREAD=1 -DMPFR_HAVE_FESETROUND=1 -DHAVE_DENORMS=1 -DHAVE_DENORMS_FLT=1 -DHAVE_SIGNEDZ=1 -DHAVE_ROUND=1 -DHAVE_TRUNC=1 -DHAVE_FLOOR=1 -DHAVE_CEIL=1 -DHAVE_NEARBYINT=1 -DHAVE_LDOUBLE_IEEE_EXT_LITTLE=1 -DMPFR_USE_THREAD_SAFE=1 -DMPFR_USE_C11_THREAD_SAFE=1 -DMPFR_WANT_DECIMAL_FLOATS=1 -DMPFR_WANT_FLOAT128=1 -DMPFR_USE_STATIC_ASSERT=1 -DHAVE_CLOCK_GETTIME=1 -DHAVE_ATTRIBUTE_MODE=1 -DNPRINTF_J=1 -DNPRINTF_L=1 -DNPRINTF_T=1 -DHAVE___GMPN_SBPI1_DIVAPPR_Q=1 -DHAVE___GMPN_INVERT_LIMB=1 -DHAVE___GMPN_RSBLSH_N=1 -DMPFR_LONG_WITHIN_LIMB=1 -I. -I../../src/src -IC:/development-personal-builds/gmp-6.1.2/build-1/include -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -Wpointer-arith -O2 -pedantic -fomit-frame-pointer -m64 -mtune=k8 -march=k8 -MT exceptions.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/exceptions.Tpo -c -o exceptions.lo ../../src/src/exceptions.c -DDLL_EXPORT -DPIC -o .libs/exceptions.o"
```

The command is still messed up, as I now get this error:

```
libtool:   error: you cannot specify '-o' more than once
```

Out of desperation, I've also tried:

- Rolling back to MPFR 3.1.6 (the version "recommended" by the MinGW-w64 port here: https://github.com/emphasis87/libmpfr-msys2-mingw64);
- Not using a bash script and running configure directly;
- Converting the bash script to ANSI instead of UTF-8;
- Using Cygwin;

Aaargh.

Comment: Since it's an Error 1, I've been trying to work out if it's literally a problem with GCC not being given input files, so a makefile problem? Just to check, I ran make with -k and it returned Error 1 for every single command. Does anyone know how to check what commands the compiler is being fed during build?

Comment: In the call of gcc, a lot of the arguments are within quotation marks: `-DHAVE_STDINT_H=1 "-DLT_OBJDIR= ... exceptions.c"  -DDLL_EXPORT`
That looks wrong.

Comment: Yes, that seems to be the problem, as Mike suggests in his answer. I haven't been able to find where these extra double quotes are actually being placed as the quotes aren't in the makefiles.

Answer (score 1):

In this commandline:

```
C:/development-tools/msys2/usr/bin/sh.exe ../libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=compile \
gcc -DMPFR_WANT_ASSERT=1 -DHAVE_INTTYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_STDINT_H=1 -DLT_OBJDIR=\".libs/\"...
```

We see that in `-DLT_OBJDIR=\".libs/\"` there are balanced quotation marks that are escaped. However in libtool's diagnostic:

```
libtool: compile:  gcc -DMPFR_WANT_ASSERT=1 -DHAVE_INTTYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_STDINT_H=1 "-DLT_OBJDIR=\\.libs/\"...
```

we see that the first of those escaped quotes has been removed and replaced with another escape:

```
\".libs/\"  <- before
\\.libs/\"  <- after
```

and that a new unescaped quotation mark has been prepended to the macro definition:

```
 -DLT_OBJDIR=\".libs/\" <- before
"-DLT_OBJDIR=\\.libs/\" <- after
```

thus creating a quoted string argument for gcc that commences `"-DLT_OBJDIR=\\.libs/\"...`
and in fact consumes all the remainder of the commandline up to:

```
../../src/src/exceptions.c"
```

whereas in the original commandline we have:

```
../../src/src/exceptions.c
```

From where I'm sitting, I cannot explain the cause of this escape/quotation corruption,
but it is the answer to the question:

> Why does GCC (MinGW-w64) return a 'fatal error: no input files' when building MPFR?

I suggest you direct your investigation to that with the advantage of being the guy on the spot.

Comment: Thanks for spotting that. Do you know if there's any way to override libtool's arguments to a corrected list? The error doesn't seem to be present in the makefiles as the extra double quotes aren't present; maybe a problem with sh?

Comment: Please see my update Mike, I'd appreciate your advice.

Comment: `CC=` should specify
(what your choose to regard as) *your C compiler*, e.g. `gcc`. You have set it be
an *entire libtool compilation commandline*. This will inevitably bust when the
build appends its own compilation options, but in any case your compilation
contains two `-o <outputfile>` options, which is an error as compilation
can only produce one object file. I'm sorry, but I can't get you further with
this except by paying you a visit ;)

Comment: I'll put the kettle on. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I just hit the same problem trying to compile GNU GetText library on Windows with Mingw64, this article was the most relevant one I found but didn't really have a solution so I'm sharing what I found out...

I produced a small testcase demonstrating the problem:

Makefile:

```
ORIGINAL=arg1 arg2 -ARG3=\"string\" -ARG4=\"\" arg5
FIXED=$(subst ","",$(ORIGINAL))

.PHONY:all
all:
    echo ORIGINAL is: $(ORIGINAL)
    ./argdump.sh $(ORIGINAL)
    echo FIXED is: $(FIXED)
    ./argdump.sh $(FIXED)
```

Which calls to the argdump.sh script:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo Dumping arguments:
for i; do 
   echo Raw Arg: $i 
done
echo DONE.
```

Output when run in Mingw:

```
$ make
echo ORIGINAL is: arg1 arg2 -ARG3=\"string\" -ARG4=\"\" arg5
ORIGINAL is: arg1 arg2 -ARG3=\string" -ARG4="" arg5
./argdump.sh arg1 arg2 -ARG3=\"string\" -ARG4=\"\" arg5
Dumping arguments:
Raw Arg: arg1
Raw Arg: arg2
Raw Arg: -ARG3=\string" -ARG4="" arg5
DONE.
echo FIXED is: arg1 arg2 -ARG3=\""string\"" -ARG4=\""\"" arg5
FIXED is: arg1 arg2 -ARG3="string" -ARG4="" arg5
./argdump.sh arg1 arg2 -ARG3=\""string\"" -ARG4=\""\"" arg5
Dumping arguments:
Raw Arg: arg1
Raw Arg: arg2
Raw Arg: -ARG3="string"
Raw Arg: -ARG4=""
Raw Arg: arg5
DONE.
```

As can be seen dumping the "original" arguments all the trailing arguments from the first that uses a quote are clumped together - when this happens in the gnu lib makefile call to libtool.sh libtool can't process the clumped arguments correctly and you get the error like "no input files". So adding the $(subst ","",$(ARGS_VAR)) call fixes this, to be honest I found this substitution to work by experimentation so I can't tell you why it works any more than "it just does".

So for example in the GetText lib I added a line before the calls to the compiler (in the gettext-runtime/intl/Makefile.in file):

```
...
# Fix arg passing to libtool under mingw:
ifeq ($(build_os),mingw32)
  LTCOMPILE:=$(subst ","",$(LTCOMPILE))
endif
# Rules for compiling a .c file, that work even without a VPATH variable.
bindtextdom.lo: $(srcdir)/bindtextdom.c
    $(AM_V_CC)$(LTCOMPILE) -c -o $@ $(srcdir)/bindtextdom.c
dcgettext.lo: $(srcdir)/dcgettext.c
    $(AM_V_CC)$(LTCOMPILE) -c -o $@ $(srcdir)/dcgettext.c
...
```

Hope this helps the next person to experience this problem!